# Using cached UIView to set cell background view in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is my solution for setting custom grouped table view cell backgrounds:

```
- (UIView *)top
{
    if (_top) {
        return _top;
    }

    _top = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [_top setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    return _top;
}

// dot dot dot

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;

    if (maxRow == 0) {
        [cell setBackgroundView:[self lonely]];
    } else if (row == 0) {
        [cell setBackgroundView:[self top]];
    } else if (row == maxRow) {
        [cell setBackgroundView:[self bottom]];
    } else {
        [cell setBackgroundView:[self middle]];
    }
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work as expected which brings me here, but it does work when I *don't* use cached views:

```
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] init];

if (maxRow == 0) {
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
} else if (row == 0) {
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
} else if (row == maxRow) {
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
} else {
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}

[cell setBackgroundView:background];
```

---

***UPDATE:*** After Jonathan pointed out that I can't use the same view for more than one cell, I decided to follow the table view model where it has a queue of reusable cells. For my implementation, I have a queue of reusable background views (`_backgroundViewPool`):

```
@implementation RootViewController {
    NSMutableSet *_backgroundViewPool;
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
        _backgroundViewPool = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

        UITableView *tableView = [self tableView];
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 6;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%d, %d]", [indexPath section], [indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *backgroundView = [cell backgroundView];
    [_backgroundViewPool addObject:backgroundView];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
    UIColor *color = nil;


    if (maxRow == 0) {
        // single cell
        color = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else if (row == 0) {
        // top cell
        color = [UIColor redColor];
    } else if (row == maxRow) {
        // bottom cell
        color = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else {
        // middle cell
        color = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    UIView *backgroundView = nil;

    for (UIView *bg in _backgroundViewPool) {
        if (color == [bg backgroundColor]) {
            backgroundView = bg;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (backgroundView) {
        [backgroundView retain];
        [_backgroundViewPool removeObject:backgroundView];
    } else {
        backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:color];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundView:[backgroundView autorelease]];
}
```

It works except when you scroll really fast. Some of the background views disappear! I suspect the background views are still being used in more than one cell, but I really don't know what's going on because the background views are supposed to be removed from the queue once it's reused making it impossible for the background view to be used in more than one visible cell.

---

I've been looking into this since I have posted this question. The current solutions for custom background views for grouped table view cells online are unsatisfactory, they don't used cached views. Additionally, I don't want to have use the solution proposed by XJones and jszumski because it's gonna get hairy once reusable custom cells (e.g., text field cell, switch cell, slider cell) are taken into account.

Comment: Don't mix `_top` and `[self top]` in your code, simply use `_top` only.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using 4 separate cell identifiers for the "lonely, "top", "bottom", and "middle" cases and setting the `backgroundView` only once when initializing the cell?  Doing it that way lets you leverage `UITableView`'s own caching and reuse without having to write an implementation on top of it.

---

**Update**: An implementation for a grouped `UITableViewController` subclass that reuses background views with a minimal number of cell reuse identifiers (Espresso's use case).  `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` do the heavy lifting to apply or reclaim each background view, and the pooling logic is handled in `backgroundViewForStyle:`.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, JSCellBackgroundStyle) {
    JSCellBackgroundStyleTop = 0,
    JSCellBackgroundStyleMiddle,
    JSCellBackgroundStyleBottom,
    JSCellBackgroundStyleSolitary
};

@implementation JSMasterViewController {
    NSArray *backgroundViewPool;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // these mutable arrays will be indexed by JSCellBackgroundStyle values
    backgroundViewPool = @[[NSMutableArray array],  // for JSCellBackgroundStyleTop
                           [NSMutableArray array],  // for JSCellBackgroundStyleMiddle
                           [NSMutableArray array],  // for JSCellBackgroundStyleBottom
                           [NSMutableArray array]]; // for JSCellBackgroundStyleSolitary
}


#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 2) {
        return 1;

    } else if (section == 3) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    static NSString *switchCellIdentifier = @"switchCell";
    static NSString *textFieldCellIdentifier = @"fieldCell";
    static NSString *textCellIdentifier = @"textCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    // apply a cached cell type (you would use your own logic to choose types of course)
    if (row % 3 == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:switchCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:switchCellIdentifier];

            UISwitch *someSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            cell.accessoryView = someSwitch;

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Switch Cell";
        }

    } else if (row % 3 == 1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textFieldCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:textFieldCellIdentifier];

            UITextField *someField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30)];
            someField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            cell.accessoryView = someField;

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Field Cell";
        }

    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:textCellIdentifier];

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Generic Label Cell";
        }
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%d, %d]", section, row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // apply a cached background view
    JSCellBackgroundStyle backgroundStyle = [self backgroundStyleForIndexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView];
    cell.backgroundView = [self backgroundViewForStyle:backgroundStyle];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    JSCellBackgroundStyle backgroundStyle = [self backgroundStyleForIndexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView];
    NSMutableArray *stylePool = backgroundViewPool[backgroundStyle];

    // reclaim the background view for the reuse pool
    [cell.backgroundView removeFromSuperview];

            if (cell.backgroundView != nil) {
            [stylePool addObject:cell.backgroundView];
            }

    cell.backgroundView = nil; // omitting this line will cause some rows to appear without a background because they try to be in two superviews at once
}

- (JSCellBackgroundStyle)backgroundStyleForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath tableView:(UITableView*)tableView {
    NSInteger maxRow = MAX(0, [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1); // catch the case of a section with 0 rows

    if (maxRow == 0) {
        return JSCellBackgroundStyleSolitary;

    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return JSCellBackgroundStyleTop;

    } else if (indexPath.row == maxRow) {
        return JSCellBackgroundStyleBottom;

    } else {
        return JSCellBackgroundStyleMiddle;
    }
}

- (UIView*)backgroundViewForStyle:(JSCellBackgroundStyle)style {
    NSMutableArray *stylePool = backgroundViewPool[style];

    // if we have a reusable view available, remove it from the pool and return it
    if ([stylePool count] > 0) {
        UIView *reusableView = stylePool[0];
        [stylePool removeObject:reusableView];

        return reusableView;

    // if we don't have any reusable views, make a new one and return it
    } else {
        UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"Created a new view for style %i", style);

        switch (style) {
            case JSCellBackgroundStyleTop:
                newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                break;

            case JSCellBackgroundStyleMiddle:
                newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                break;

            case JSCellBackgroundStyleBottom:
                newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
                break;

            case JSCellBackgroundStyleSolitary:
                newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                break;
        }

        return newView;
    }
}

@end
```

Although you could very easily get away with dumping all views into one reuse pool, it complicates some of the looping logic and this way is easier to comprehend.

Comment: I have looked into doing this, but I don't wanna have to do this because it's gonna get hairy once reusable custom cells (e.g., text field cell, switch cell, slider cell) are taken into account.

Comment: Did you test your code? I've managed to make it crash when the keyboard is presented. Apparently `nil` is being added to the pool.

Comment: I did but not that case.  A `nil` check should be pretty easy to add.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I would check why this kind of caching is necessary. If it's a performance problem, I would check that the problem is indeed the views, and not something else like too many blended layers!

Regarding the caching, there are several approaches. At least three come to mind:

1. For each of the four backgrounds, register an own cell reuse identifier. Then set the background view depending on the reuse identifier.
2. Use an own cache for the background views, and reuse background views from there.
3. Use the same class for background views on all cells, and set the content on them only.

The first solution is quite easy to implement, but it holds the risk that the `UITableView` ends up holding lots of cells for reusing that are not needed. Also, if you need more types of cells, you would have to provide cells for each type/background combination.

While the second solution reuses cell backgrounds, you have to write an own cache for those, and to set/unset backgrounds where necessary.

The third solution only works if the background view can be configured to show the background for the respective cell. It would reuse the content only, not the background views themselves.

Here is an early screenshot of a test for the second solution:

[image: Screenshot showing a customized grouped table view]

Here is the implementation:

```
@implementation RootViewController
{
    NSMutableDictionary *_backgroundViews;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _backgroundViews = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 100;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return section / 10 + 1;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (!cell.backgroundView || ![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
        NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
        NSString *imageName = nil;
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        if (maxRow == 0) {
            // single cell
            imageName = @"singlebackground";
            insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12);
        } else if (row == 0) {
            // top cell
            imageName = @"topbackground";
            insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 0, 12);
        } else if (row == maxRow) {
            // bottom cell
            imageName = @"bottombackground";
            insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 12, 12);
        } else {
            // middle cell
            imageName = @"middlebackground";
            insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12);
        }

        NSMutableSet *backgrounds = [_backgroundViews objectForKey:imageName];
        if (backgrounds == nil) {
            backgrounds = [NSMutableSet set];
            [_backgroundViews setObject:backgrounds forKey:imageName];
        }

        UIImageView *backgroundView = nil;
        for (UIImageView *candidate in backgrounds) {
            if (candidate.superview == nil) {
                backgroundView = candidate;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (backgroundView == nil) {
            backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            backgroundView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            backgroundView.opaque = YES;
        }
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%d, %d]", [indexPath section], [indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

If you would like to check it out, here are the images I used (non-retina only and too big, but hey, it's only an example):

- singlebackground.png:

  [image: singlebackground.png]
- topbackground.png:

  [image: topbackground.png]
- middlebackground.png:

  [image: middlebackground.png]
- bottombackground.png:

  [image: bottombackground.png]

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a view twice at the same time, which would occure when you have more than 3 cells. The reuising mechanism of the table should be sufficient enough.

I am not sure why u want to handle the backgroundViews seperatly from the cells. 
Anyways, i altered your code so that there is no bug with missing backgroundViews:

NOTE! i did use ARC.

```
static NSString *identifierSingle = @"single";
static NSString *identifierTop = @"top";
static NSString *identifierBtm = @"btm";
static NSString *identifierMid = @"mid";


@implementation RootViewController {
    NSMutableDictionary *_backgroundViewPool;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
        _backgroundViewPool = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        UITableView *tableView = [self tableView];
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 6;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 10;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView identifierForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;

    if (maxRow == 0) {
        // single cell
        return identifierSingle;
    } else if (row == 0) {
        // top cell
        return identifierTop;
    } else if (row == maxRow) {
        // bottom cell
        return identifierBtm;
    } else {
        // middle cell
        return identifierMid;
    }
}

- (UIColor *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView colorForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
    UIColor *color = nil;


    if (maxRow == 0) {
        // single cell
        color = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else if (row == 0) {
        // top cell
        color = [UIColor redColor];
    } else if (row == maxRow) {
        // bottom cell
        color = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else {
        // middle cell
        color = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return color;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *colorIdentifier = [self tableView:tableView identifierForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%d, %d]", [indexPath section], [indexPath row]]];
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    NSMutableSet *set = [self backgroundPoolForIdentifier:colorIdentifier];
    UIView *backgroundView = [set anyObject];;

    if (backgroundView) {
        [set removeObject:backgroundView];
    } else {
        backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[self tableView:tableView colorForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundView:backgroundView];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (NSMutableSet *)backgroundPoolForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableSet *set = [_backgroundViewPool valueForKey:identifier];
    if (!set) {
        set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        [_backgroundViewPool setValue:set forKey:identifier];
    }
    return set;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[self backgroundPoolForIdentifier:cell.reuseIdentifier] addObject:cell.backgroundView];
}

@end
```

Comment: @espresso, this is a reasonable cache implementation, certainly an improvement over your original code. I'm still guessing a bit as to what your goal is. We're all telling you to rethink implementing a view cache outside of what tableView already provides. If you are concerned with drawing code in your custom background view this cache may not fully do what you want. It depends if `layoutSubviews` or `drawRect` is called when the cached background view is added to the cell. You can use @jonathan's method to generate the identifier and append that to a cell type ID and not use a custom cache.

Comment: Your view caching definitely works. Any idea why my implementation doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - using images as a background view**

Given your comments on my answer it seems like you want to display images in the background view of your cells. It is not clear if these images are compiled into your app as resources or downloaded from a service. Regardless, you can use the same `UIImage` instance in multiple `UIImageView` instances. So as you create your cells, you can create a new `UIImageView` on the fly for use as the background view and then set the `image` property to the appropriate `UIImage` based on the cell's indexPath.

If the images are compiled into your app then `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` uses an iOS implemented cache and will perform well. If you are downloading images (presumably on a background thread) then you will need to implement a disk and/or memory cache for your image data.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

When you configure your cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use the cell identifier to use the built-in caching of the `tableView` to cache cells with the various background views for you.

Something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *singleCellID = @"single";
    static NSString *firstCellID = @"first";
    static NSString *middleCellID = @"middle";
    static NSString *lastCellID = @"last";

    NSString *cellID = nil;

    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
    UIColor *color = nil;

    if (maxRow == 0) {
        // single cell
        cellID = singleCellID;
    } else if (row == 0) {
        // top cell
        cellID = firstCellID;
    } else if (row == maxRow) {
        // bottom cell
        cellID = lastCellID;
    } else {
        // middle cell
        cellID = middleCellID;
   }

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell == nil) {
       if (cellID == singleCellID) {
           // create single cell
           cell = ...
           cell.backgroundView = ...
       }
       else if (cellID == firstCellID) {
           // create first cell
           cell = ...
           cell.backgroundView = ...
       }
       else if (cellID == lastCellID) {
           // create last cell
           cell = ...
           cell.backgroundView = ...
       }
       else {
           // create middle cell
           cell = ...
           cell.backgroundView = ...
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have looked into doing this, but I don't wanna have to do this because it's gonna get hairy once reusable custom cells (e.g., text field cell, switch cell, slider cell) are taken into account.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hairy" but this is the right way to do this. You should have different cell types for different behaviors. This is the intended use and why Apple has implemented `UITableView` this way.

Comment: Suppose you have multiple reusable custom cells. How is that going to look with your solution? I'm going to have cell identifiers like `TextFieldCell-Single`, `TextFieldCell-Top`, `TextFieldCell-Middle`, `TextFieldCell-Bottom`, `SwitchCell-Single`, `SwitchCell-Top`...

Comment: well, actually, I would have a custom cell for each of your main types (text field, switch,etc) and then I would simply create the appropriate background view when configuring the cell. there's really no need to cache the background view. do you actually have a performance issue creating your background views on the fly?

Comment: If you **must** implement caching, I would still do it via the built-in table view cache and I would append a position identifier to the cell ID for each cell type, so yes, "TextFieldMiddle" etc. However, I still think this is a bad approach and I wouldn't bother caching the background views. Even when they background contains a 'UIImage' you will be fine w/o caching. Think about all the photo apps that display different photos as content (not backgrounds) as content within cells.

Comment: I agree with almost everything XJones has said.  Generally the hardest part of the implementation is making the custom cells, which you would still only need to do once per type.  @Espresso, in the future it would help to specify all of the various constraints upfront in the original question.  I would caution you not to over optimize before you've proven that it is a problem.  If you *have* proven it, can you update the question with that info?

Comment: @Espresso XJones, and jszumski provided adequate answers, you shouldn't implement your own caching mechanism, uitableview does it for you. Also, I doubt that you can set a UIView instance in willDisplayCell, as pointed out in Apple Docs, this delegate is used to "override state-based properties". A new UIView is a new layout state, and requires a new layout run. Finally, you'll have to make a cell-by-cell assignment, whatever solution you choose. Why not trying a state assignment matrix as a separate method, called in CellForRow? This might lighten-up your code, and make it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
Ok, so, as far as you use custom background view, I think you should assign your background view to cell's .backgroundView property in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and do not use your own views caching mechanism, because table view caches entire cell with all it's subviews - you assign background view when you create cell and later just update it's backgroundColor with proper value (in your case, based on index path).

Also, this is just a suggestion, your background view might be obscured with cell's other content (e.g. you added something to .contentView) - try setting cell / contentView .alpha value to 0.5 to be able to see through it. Code is still related - this method is called every time UITableView needs new cell to display on the screen

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
    static NSString* identifer = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifer];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifer];
        cell.backgroundView = [YourCustomView new];//assign your custom background view here
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    //update background view's color based on index path row
    if(indexPath.row==0)
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else if(indexPath.row==1)
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    else
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Nope. I actually have a subclassed UIView that does some drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Your original implementation didnt work because in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you sometimes  returning a nil object. UITableView framework then passes that *cell object to `willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)`.

```
ie: 

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
....
return cell;

// cell maybe nil
```

If you do indeed perfer using your own caching mechanism, you can simply return a plain UITableViewCell object, dequeued if available or create a new one if none is available for reuse.

```
ie:

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] 
        || [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
        ;
}
```

Then, there is the "view can only be added to 1 superview limit" causing your cached view to appear jumping.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a), when a cell is **dequeued**, it still has all it's views and settings you previously set.

Therefore, if you set a background view to cell it would still be there when it's dequeued and if it's a new cell it won't have  background view.

I believe you  **don't need the background view pool** since the OS handles that for you, so you can just **reuse the BG** view as you reuse the cell and do something like that in `willDisplayCell:` only

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
  NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
  NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
  UIColor *color = nil;


  if (maxRow == 0) {
    // single cell
    color = [UIColor blueColor];
  } else if (row == 0) {
    // top cell
    color = [UIColor redColor];
  } else if (row == maxRow) {
    // bottom cell
    color = [UIColor greenColor];
  } else {
    // middle cell
    color = [UIColor yellowColor];
  }

  UIView *backgroundView = nil;

  //***This is the different part***//

  if (cell.backgroundView != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Old Cell, reuse BG View");
    backgroundView = cell.backgroundView;
  } else {
    NSLog(@"New Cell, Create New BG View");
    backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [cell setBackgroundView:[backgroundView autorelease]];
  }

  [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:color];  
}
```

Like that there is no need for the code `didEndDisplayingCell:` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tried several things to do this but finally got satisfied on this very basic solutions, i know it's not really a charming one but it gave me smooth scrolling, you can try this if you like:

```
NSMutableArray *_viewArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    #define kTotalNoOfRows 1000
        _viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kTotalNoOfRows];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   for (int i = 0; i < kTotalNoOfRows; i++) {
        UIView * backGroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

        if (kTotalNoOfRows == 0)
            [backGroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        else if (i == 0)
            [backGroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        else if (i == (kTotalNoOfRows - 1))
            [backGroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        else
            [backGroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

        [_viewArray addObject:backGroundView];        
    }

    return kTotalNoOfRows;
}


- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
    static NSString* middleCell = @"middleCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:middleCell];
    if(cell==nil) {
        NSInteger maxRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1;
        if (maxRow != 0 && indexPath.row != 0 && indexPath.row != maxRow) {
            middleCell = nil;
        }
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:middleCell];
        cell.backgroundView = [_viewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//assign your custom background view here
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Also I would like to mention my journey towards here; So what I have tried is

- created a dictionary of Views:

  ```
  UIView * _topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
  UIView * _bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
  UIView * _middleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
  UIView * _lonelyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
  [_topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [_bottomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
  [_middleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
  [_lonelyView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
  _viewDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _topView, @"topView",
                                   _bottomView, @"bottomView",
                                   _middleView, @"middleView",
                                   _lonelyView, @"lonelyView", nil];
  ```
- returned copy of these view with unarchiver

  ```
  - (UIView *) getBackgroundViewWith : (NSInteger) maxRow currentRow : (NSInteger) row{
      if (maxRow == 0) {
          return (UIView *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"lonelyView"]]];//[[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"lonelyView"] copy];
      } else if (row == 0) {
          return (UIView *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"topView"]]];//[[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"topView"] copy];
      } else if (row == maxRow) {
          return (UIView *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"bottomView"]]];//[[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"bottomView"] copy];
      } else {
          return (UIView *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"middleView"]]];//[[_viewDictionary valueForKey:@"middleView"] copy];
      }
      return nil;
  }
  ```

But it crash, while scrolling table with `SIGBART`. Thus gave up with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with tableviews, but I vaguely recall running into this problem.  I believe the calls to the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method are threaded.  When the user scrolls very fast multiple calls can get out simultaneously.  In that case, given your current code, it is possible for multiple cells to get assigned the same view which will then cause the blank spaces.

If you use @synchronized(anObject){} to prevent multiple threads from running the same code simultaneously, you should be able to prevent the problem.

```
@synchronized (self) {
    UIView *backgroundView = nil;

    for (UIView *bg in _backgroundViewPool) {
        if (color == [bg backgroundColor]) {
            backgroundView = bg;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (backgroundView) {
        [backgroundView retain];
        [_backgroundViewPool removeObject:backgroundView];
    } else {
        backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:color];
    }
}
```